# How do you set the Meteor.userId() for use within autoform/simple-schema?

Tags: javascript, meteor

Say I want to display a list a user's shopping items once they are logged in.  I'm using autoform and simple-schema to generate the form elements.  When the user logs in for the first time a blank shopping list form is displayed.  When submitting the form the shopping list is saved in the db.

What I want to know is how I can save this data for each user.

Normally I would do something like this:

```
      ShoppingList.insert({
        name: item_name,
        price: 0,
        createdBy: Meteor.userId()
      });
```

How would I acheive this using autoform and simple-schema?  Would it be possible to do something like this:

```
Schema.ShoppingList = new SimpleSchema({
item: {
    type: String,
    regEx: /^[a-zA-Z-]{2,25}$/
},
price: {
    type: Number,
    regEx: /^[0-9]{2,25}$/
},
createdBy: {
    type: String,
    value: Meteor.userId()
}
});
```

Thanks again :)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

If you are using also Collection2 then use autoValue:

```
Schema.ShoppingList = new SimpleSchema({
item: {
    type: String,
    regEx: /^[a-zA-Z-]{2,25}$/
},
price: {
    type: Number,
    regEx: /^[0-9]{2,25}$/
},
createdBy: {
    type: String,
    autoValue:function(){ return this.userId }
}
});
```

Read more : 
https://github.com/aldeed/meteor-collection2/

Comment: That's great thank you, I got that working.  I've had a look at the docs too.  I've got the form displaying using quickForm.  By adding in the createdBy field to the schema that's obviously displaying a form element.  Is there anyway to hide it?  It doesn't need displayed as its just going to store the userId in the DB.

Comment: In documentation of quickform you can find: **[fields](https://github.com/aldeed/meteor-autoform)** `: Optional. Bind an array or specify a comma-delimited string of field names to include. Only the listed fields (and their subfields, if any) will be included, and they'll appear in the order you specify.`

Comment: That's brilliant thank you.  I used omitFields and that worked perfectly.  I think I'll spend some time getting more familiar with the docs!

Comment: you can also use:         autoform: {
            type: "hidden",
            label: false
        },

Comment: you can also call a separate method upon submit of the autoform, specified with the meteormethod= paramater to {{#autoform}} , and with that, you can do extra things before saving to Mongo, like adding a createdBy field.

Comment: Use it with CAUTION!. If another user can update this collection (like adding a comments or voting) createdBy will be replaced to the CURRENT user.

Answer (score 5):

This worked for me:

```
creatorID: {
    type: String,
    regEx: SimpleSchema.RegEx.Id,
    autoform: {
        type: "hidden",
        label: false
    },
    autoValue: function () { return Meteor.userId() },
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`this.userId()` didn't work for me, instead this did:

```
    autoValue: function() {
        return Meteor.user()._id;
    }
```